# Why isn't my onSaveInstanceState saving my EditText Value properly when going from landscape back to portrait

Tags: java, android

So I have seen multiple examples of this done and for some reason I cannot get onSaveInstanceState to save the value of my EditText properly.

I have a very simple example that looks just like the image below.

[image]

first a **TextView**, then an **EditText** followed by a **Button**.

When clicking the Button it saves the value in EditText and then applies it to the TextView.

So the problem is it only works once, meaning I start in Portrait mode then turn my phone to Landscape and it saves then back to Portrait and it does not so the TextView appears blank.

My Example code is below:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    tools:context="mydomain.com.savetest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Default Text"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="choose a word"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAVE WORD"
        android:id="@+id/bu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package mydomain.com.savetest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private Button mButton;
    private String editTextValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        editTextValue = mEditText.getText().toString();
        mTextView.setText(editTextValue);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            mTextView.setText( savedInstanceState.getString("text") ); //setting the saved value to the TextView
        }


        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editTextValue = mEditText.getText().toString();
                mTextView.setText(editTextValue);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString("text", editTextValue); //saving EditText value
    }
}
```

So the whole goal of this is to get the TextView to save the word that was int the EditText and maintain it switching from portrait to landscape. As of now if I type lets say "Car" it will update the TextView with "Car" and will also have the value of Car even turning to Landscape mode, BUT when turning back to portrait the TextView value is gone and has nothing. I Cant seem to figure out whats going on here because I have set the value of EditText to TextView in the beginning on onCreate() so when the app starts again it should take the saved value just fine.

Comment: may be you're making a mistake in inputs. if you write 'car' in `EditText` and rotate the device. the `TextView` shows 'car' but if you again rotate it without writing anything in the `EditText`, the 'TextView' will become blank as this time empty string was stored in the 'EditText' and your code copied the same to `TextView`.

Comment: you can also try this outState.putString("text", mEditText.getText().toString());

Comment: @AkashRaghav But if you rotate the device to landscape the value within the "TextEdit" does NOT change, in other words I still see car when I rotate the device. So why would it be grabbing a blank value?

Comment: Try adding an `@id` to the `RelativeLayout` in the XML file.

Comment: @LucasSantos: Sorry to ping on an unrelated question but I was working on the solution to your z-index problem and it seems like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qkp690re/3/) maybe what you need. If it is, please undelete the other question and I will add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the current text directly from `EditText` instead of relying on a `String` variable being initialized in `OnClickListener()` once. It works only once because you've pressed the button once.. After the 2nd orientation change, the button wasn't pressed and hence `String editTextValue` is more likely null, because you would have to press the button after each orientation..

Change somethings as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //don't save EditText value in a variable, instead directly get it from the EditText.
    outState.putString("text", mEditText.getText().toString()); 
}
```

also remove the variable initialization from `OnClickListener()` Its not needed

```
 editTextValue = mEditText.getText().toString(); // remove this.
```

Comment: Well the String variable that I was using was not only being used once, it was also being used on the onCreate() method so ever time the app starts the activity it would assign that value to the TextView. I thought it would work because if you rotate to landscape the value of the EditText remains the same. So I still do not understand why it did not work but your method worked great.

Comment: Instead of using the String variable in `onCreate`, use it directly like I did. `mEditText.getText().toString()`